# LNK2020 & LNK1120 errors in old class in old working project since other project added that includes same class

Tags: static, linker, refactoring, c++-cli, linker-errors

I am getting unexpected linker errors after refactoring my solution from 1 to 3 projects. In this first instance I get two unresolved tokens, like

> error LNK2020: unresolved token (0600000C) Mynamespace.MyClass::unresolvedStaticFunc
>
> error LNK2020: unresolved token (0600000C) Mynamespace.MyClass::unresolvedOtherStaticFunc
>
> fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

I have not touched this class in my refactoring. Both methods are declared static in the header but not the body (cpp file).

I've rechecked my errors and the new project is compiling fine but forcing the old one to break on linking.

I think I need to add files to my new projects but they seem nicely separated into their own folders now. Another project for the shared class perhaps? I am adding what I thought a simple feature and my project count has already tripled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be `#include`ing header files containing managed types across multiple projects. Instead, in the new project, add an assembly reference to the old project; this way, the type information will be gathered from the .NET metadata embedded into the old project's assembly.

Comment: Thanks, I'd completely forgotten about references. Namespace are also fairly new to me, at present they are all the same, I feel this has introduced the next round of errors presented me - or i might just need to refactor out a circular reference...